# Are there any human factions besides the Imperium, the forces of Chaos, and Tau's human auxilia?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Are there any independent human factions that are not part of the Imperium, Chaos, or the Tau?

I know that there were many human factions before the Great Crusade, but what about now?  If yes, are any of these factions at peace with the Imperium?

Answer (score 5):

There are also humans on not yet recaptured planets from the *Dark Age of Technology*. An example, from the *[Rogue Trader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_Trader_(role-playing_game))* RPG is *Zayth*:

> Zayth is a world scarred deeply by war. Enormous vehicles the size of cities churn the surface of Zayth’s single macro-continent. Each is a fortress and weapon platform armed with fearsome devices of war and destruction. Within them dwell Zayth’s human population, protected from the radiation and toxins unleashed by centuries of warfare. Zayth’s surface has been barren for millennia, ploughed and poisoned by shellfire, rapacious, urgent strip-mining, and the passage of hive-vehicles. Despite their weaponry and extraordinary vehicle cities the humans of Zayth have fallen far from the knowledge of their ancestors in all but war, and the knowledge of producing their hive-vehicles is long vanished. Great generators and engine vaults are permanently sealed by copper doors or guarded by hereditary Engine Orders who guard the traditions and culture of each clan fortress. Upon war-torn Zayth, each hive-vehicle circulates its own coinage---often small stamped ingots of precious metals hung upon loops of silver wire.
>
> From [this Wiki-Article](https://calixipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Zayth)

They are not at peace with the Empire but only planets waiting to be captured by Rogue Traders or a crusade.

Furthermore, the *Dark Eldarr* have human slaves (don't know if you count them):

> The lure of thousands of souls to be enslaved and tortured and immense amounts of wealth to be plundered can draw Dark Eldar together to face a large or very well-defended target.
>
> From [this Wiki-Article](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Eldar)